# s:submit returns the label value when access the value from java script

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am trying to access the button value, but it returns the label value instead of value given in `s:submit`.

```
 <s:submit type="button" value="ForgotPassword" label="Forgot Password Label" onclick="checkval(this.val)"
```

But `this.value` gives me label value (Forgot Password Label) instead of value `i` define.

What is the cause for this behavior?

Comment: See what HTML is rendered for the button. That will tell you whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

try using `this.attr('value').val()` instead of `this.val`